# how to drop rows of wrong type in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['1','2','92#']})
test_df

    foo
0   1
1   2
2   92#
```

I want to convert the type to int64:

```
test_df.foo.astype('int64')
```

but I got error message because '92#' can't be convert to int64:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '92#'

So I want to drop all rows that can't convert to int64, and got my result like this:

```
    foo
0   1
1   2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a solution that applies to the dataFrame as a whole, call `pd.to_numeric` through `apply`, and use the resultant mask to drop rows:

```
test_df[test_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna()].dropna()

  foo
0   1
1   2
```

This does not modify `test_df`'s values. OTOH, if you want to drop rows while converting values, your solution simplifies:

```
test_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()

   foo
0  1.0
1  2.0
```

Add an `.astype(int)` call at the end if you want the result typecast to `int64`.

Comment: Didn't know about `.notna` should pay more attention to the what's new section +1

Comment: @EdChum Ah yes, it's a .22 thing. Although I should mention that it's got issues in terms of backwards compatibility pandas code and is a few microseconds slower than `notnull` to boot. Pandas devs are weird... xD